# How to save an updated fits file with headers in correct places?

Tags: astropy, astronomy, fits

I want to edit the data in my fits file using astropy and then save it to its original file. Below is my code and the error message, please ignore if there's a redundant line because obviously I opened the file twice but I still get the error after deleting it.

```
file_list = sorted(glob.glob('*.fits'))    #read in my three fits files
hdudata = np.full((3,720,1440), 0)         # a test list to store the data

for im in range(len(file_list)):
    hdu_list = fits.open(file_list[im])
    hdudata[im] = hdu_list[0].data    # read in the data from fits file
    if im == 2:                       # I only want to change the last image
        with fits.open(file_list[im], mode='update') as hdus:
            hdu = hdus[0]
            hdu.data = (hdudata[im-1] + hdudata[im])/2.    # basically add two images
                                                           # and take the average
            hdu.close()    # this is required otherwise an error message pops up saying
                                # the next line cannot proceed as the file is being run
            hdu.flush()         # the error line


VerifyError: 
Verification reported errors:
HDU 0:
    'NAXIS1' card at the wrong place (card 4).
    'NAXIS2' card at the wrong place (card 5).
    'EXTEND' card at the wrong place (card 6).
Note: astropy.io.fits uses zero-based indexing.
```

I have only accessed and changed the data but why is the error taking place in my header, I met no problem reading the headers (though I didn't include in this code above) then why is it faulty when saving it?

Comment: Check out https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/verification.html#fits-io-verification.  You might try `hdu.verify='fix'` (see https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#working-with-non-standard-files)

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly the problem, but some things might also be confused because you're opening the file in read mode, but then while it's already open, re-opening it in a `with` block with `mode='update'`.  There shouldn't be any reason to do that.  Just open the file in the first place with `mode='update'`.  The stuff where you wrote `hdu.close(); hdu.flush()` shouldn't be necessary either--the errors you mentioned in the comments are probably related to this.

Comment: You might also be hitting some version of [this issue](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/11312) where updating the data in a FITS file can result in unnecessary rewrites of the header, even if the data format didn't change at all as seems to be the case here.

Comment: Thanks both, the code does look messy and as I said there are redundant lines, so after tidying it up and using hdu.verify='fix' it works now!